# How to config JBoss Eap 6.4 to serve images from an external folder outside webapps?

Tags: jboss, jboss6.x

I have an application deployed on JBoss Eap 6.4 and I need to access to images that are located outside of my project in C:\AdminCont\Images, Is there any form to configure for JSP access to this images or any other form using NFS?

I´m trying using overlay in jboss-web.xml but I don´t know how is the correct implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A portable way to implement this is to write a small servlet which simply maps the request URL to a filesystem location and sends the content out.

A not portable way, a JBoss specific way, is to declare an outside directory to `<overlay>` in `jboss-web.xml` in order to add non-existing files to your deployment. Here is an example:

```
<jboss-web version="7.0" 
        xmlns:jboss="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee jboss-web_7_0.xsd">
    ...
    <overlay>/path/to/your/images/</overlay>
    ...
</jboss-web>
```

Comment: relative path also can be used like <overlay>${jboss.server.base.dir}/someFolder/</overlay>